# Unable to render d3 chart in table cells

Tags: angular, d3.js

currently using angular 7 with d3 v7.
Trying to render area chart in each cell of table (shown in picture below). But using angular method the rendered svg keeps rendering in a loop. Not sure what im doing wrong here
[image]

HTML Code

```
<tr [id]="'row' + '-' + fleet" *ngFor="let fleet of fleetcolumn">
      <td>{{ fleet }}</td>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let station of formattedBaseStations | slice: 1">
        <td style="width: 28em;">
              <div [id]="'demandChartInTable1-' + station + '-' + fleet + '-A'"> {{d3DemandChartIntable(station, fleet, 'A')}} </div>
            </mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile class="FOChart">
              <div [id]="'demandChartInTable1-' + station + '-' + fleet + '-B'"> {{d3DemandChartIntable(station, fleet, 'A')}} </div>
            </mat-grid-tile>
          </mat-grid-list>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
```

.ts code

```
    d3DemandChartIntable(station, code, position) {
    // set data
    let temp1 = this.data
      .filter(d => d.baseCode == station && d.code == code && d.position == position)
      .map(d => {
        return {
          date: d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d')(d.date),
          hours: d.hours
        };
      });
    const e = document.querySelector('.captainChart');
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    const margin = { top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 1, left: 1 },
      width = 120 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 90 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    const svg = d3
      .select(`#demandChartInTable1-${station}-${fleet}-${position}`)
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', e.clientWidth + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', e.clientHeight + margin.bottom)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

    const x = d3
      .scaleTime()
      .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date))
      .range([0, e.clientWidth]);

    // Y axis
    const y = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 500])
      .range([e.clientHeight + margin.bottom, 0]);

    // Add the area
    return svg
      .append('path')
      .datum(temp1)
      .attr('fill', '#cce5df')
      .attr('stroke', '#69b3a2')
      .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
      .attr(
        'd',
        d3
          .area()
          .x(d => x(d.date))
          .y0(y(0))
          .y1(d => y(d.hours))
      );
  }
```

**Above code renders repeated svg in each cell instead of rendering just once**

[image]

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It would greatly help if you could create a [mre] of your code, preferably in a StackBlitz or a [runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). That way, we can more easily answer your question and you'll be more likely to get a good answer

Comment: @RubenHelsloot please see minimal reproduction here https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-merkle-2zjms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crux is in the following code:

```js
const svg = d3
      .select(`#demandChartInTable1-${station}-${fleet}-${position}`)
      .append('svg')
```

It selects the table cell and then appends an SVG element. That means that if an SVG already exists, another one is added next to it. If you want to solve this issue, you can either

- Select and update the existing SVG and only create one once (for example in `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit`);
- Delete any existing SVGs and draw a new one, using

```js
const cell = d3.select(`#demandChartInTable1-${station}-${fleet}-${position}`);
cell.remove('*');
const svg = cell.append('svg')
```